A coordinate free interpretation of the "lowering the indices" operation
Let $ E $ be a vector space equipped with a non-degenerate bilinear pairing $ g\colon E\times E\to \mathbb R $.
Let $ \{e_1,\dots,e_n\} $ be a basis of $ E $ (not necessarily orthonormal) and consider an element
$$
a = a^{\mu_1\dots\mu_k}e_{\mu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{\mu_k}
$$
in $ \bigwedge\nolimits^kE $. In the physicists' dystopia one "lowers the indices" of $ a $ in the following way:
$$
a_{\nu_1\dots\nu_k} = g_{\mu_1\nu_1}\dots g_{\mu_k\nu_k}a^{\mu_1\dots\mu_k}
$$
where $ g_{\mu\nu} = g(e_\mu,e_\nu) $. I would like to show that the vector
$$
a^\flat = a_{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}e^{\nu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e^{\nu_k}
$$
of $ \bigwedge\nolimits^k(E^*) $, where $ \{e^1,\dots,e^n\} $ is the dual basis, has the following coordinate free origin.
First of all, observe that there's a unique (non-degenerate) bilinear pairing
$$
g^{(k)}\colon \bigwedge\nolimits^kE\times \bigwedge\nolimits^kE\to \mathbb R
$$
extending the map
$$
g^{(k)}(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k,w_1\wedge\dots\wedge w_k) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\operatorname{sign}\sigma\prod_{j = 1}^k g(v_j,w_{\sigma(j)})
$$
defined on the elementary wedge products, where $ S_k $ is the symmetric group.
Intuitively, it should be that
$$
a^\flat = g^{(k)}(a,{-})\in \left(\bigwedge\nolimits^k E\right)^*
$$
under the obvious identification
$$
\left(\bigwedge\nolimits^k E\right)^* \cong \bigwedge\nolimits^k(E^*)\,\text{,}\label{iso}\tag{$1$}
$$
but I don't know how to prove it (that sum over al the $ k $-permutations is annoying).
EDIT. As required by @Martin Brandenburg I'll specify below the isomorphism $ \eqref{iso} $ above.
There's a bilinear (perfect) pairing
$$
B\colon E^*\times E\to \mathbb R
$$
and one can lift $ B $ to a bilinear (perfect) pairing
$$
B^{(k)}\colon \bigwedge\nolimits^k(E^*)\times \bigwedge\nolimits^k E\to \mathbb R
$$
working as I did before: first define
$$
B^{(k)}(\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^k,v_1,\dots,v_k) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\operatorname{sign}\sigma\prod_{j = 1}^k B(\alpha^j,v^{\sigma(j)}) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\operatorname{sign}\sigma\prod_{j = 1}^k\alpha^j(v_{\sigma(j)})
$$
and then extend by multilinearity. In this way one obtains an isomorphism
$$
\left(\bigwedge\nolimits^k E\right)^* \xrightarrow{\cong} \bigwedge\nolimits^k(E^*)
$$
that maps
$$
\overbrace{(e_{\mu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{\mu_k})^*}^{\text{some element of the dual basis of the $ e_{\mu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{\mu_k} $s}}\mapsto \overbrace{e^{\mu_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e^{\mu_k}}^{\text{a real wedge product of elements of the dual basis $ e^{\mu_j} $ of the basis of the $ e_{\mu_j} $}}
$$

Please write down the definition of your "obvious identification" (which is some specific isomorphism, after all) and add it to the equation you want to prove. Reason is that any proof will of course use the formula of this "obvious identification". Also please add what you have tried.

Edited! As for what I have tried: after having written $ \alpha $ in the basis of the elementary wedges, I inserted it into $ g^{(k)} $ and then I mechanically tried to compute the expansion of the vector $ g^{(k)}(\alpha,{-}) $ in the right basis of elementary wedges. As I said, the problem is that such an expansion necessarily contains a "$ \sum_{\sigma\in S_k} $" term which I don't know how to get rid of.

I recommend you simplify notation for the summation by observing that’s just the definition of the determinant of the $k\times k$ matrix $(g(v_i,w_j))$.
Also, I think you should have a $\frac{1}{k!}$ in front of your summation for $a$ because the wedge is already alternating (well this is the case if you’re using the wedge conventions like those in Spivak’s Calculus on Manifolds)… anyway, this isn’t super important.

First, recall that for a finite-dimensional vector space $E$, we have an isomorphism $\Phi:\bigwedge^k(E^*)\to \left(\bigwedge^kE\right)^*$ such that for each $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k\in E^*$, the element $\alpha_1\wedge\cdots\wedge \alpha_k\in \bigwedge^k(E^*)$ is sent to the linear map $\Phi(\alpha_1\wedge\cdots\wedge \alpha_k):\bigwedge^kE\to\Bbb{F}$ defined on simple wedges as
\begin{align}
v_1\wedge \dots\wedge v_k\mapsto \det (\alpha_i(v_j)).
\end{align}
Since simple wedges span the exterior powers, this uniquely defines $\Phi$, and one can check it is an isomorphism.
Now, observe that for all $v_1,\dots, v_k,w_1\dots, w_k\in E$, we have
\begin{align}
\left(g_{(k)}^{\flat}(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k)\right)(w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_k)
&:=g_{(k)}(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k,w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_k)\\
&:= \det \left( g(v_i,w_j)\right)\\
&:=\det\left(g^{\flat}(v_i)(w_j)\right)\\
&:=\Phi(g^{\flat}(v_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge g^{\flat}(v_k))(w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_k).
\end{align}
Each of these steps is by definition.
Since the elementary $k$-wedges of $w$’s span $\bigwedge^kE$, it follows that
\begin{align}
g_{(k)}^{\flat}(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k)&=\Phi(g^{\flat}(v_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge g^{\flat}(v_k)).\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
The succinct way to express this equation is that $g_{(k)}^{\flat}=\Phi\circ\bigwedge^k(g^{\flat})$ (recall that for any linear map $T:V\to W$ there is an induced map on exterior powers $\bigwedge^kT:\bigwedge^kV\to \bigwedge^kW$ defined by linearly extending $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k\mapsto T(v_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge T(v_k)$).

Next, recall that if $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ is a basis of $E$ and $\{\varepsilon^1,\dots,\varepsilon^n\}$ is the dual basis for $E^*$, then $g^{\flat}(e_j)=g_{ij}\varepsilon^i$. This is because
\begin{align}
g^{\flat}(e_j)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(g^{\flat}(e_j)\right)(e_i)\cdot\varepsilon^i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ng(e_j,e_i)\,\varepsilon^i\\
&\equiv g_{ji}\varepsilon^i\\
&=g_{ij}\varepsilon^i.\tag{$**$}
\end{align}

Combining $(*)$ and $(**)$ tells us that
\begin{align}
g_{(k)}^{\flat}(e_{\mu_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{\mu_k})&=\Phi\left(g^{\flat}(e_{\mu_1})\wedge\cdots\wedge g^{\flat}(e_{\mu_k})\right)\\
&=\Phi\left(g_{\mu_1\nu_1}\varepsilon^{\nu_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge g_{\mu_k\nu_k}\varepsilon^{\nu_k}\right)\\
&=g_{\mu_1\nu_1}\cdots g_{\mu_k\nu_k}\Phi\left(\varepsilon^{\nu_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \varepsilon^{\nu_k}\right).
\end{align}
If you now stick in a bunch of coefficient $a^{\mu_1\dots\mu_k}$, you’ll get the result you’re after, namely that $g_{(k)}^{\flat}(a)$ really does have components given by your second equation.
